# Vue only renders first custom component issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple Vue app where I'm trying to render multiple custom components, here's what I'm trying:

JS

```js
Vue.component('refinement-list', {
  props: ['attribute', 'title'],
  template: '<div>{{attribute}} - {{title}}</div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <refinement-list attribute="test" title="Test" />
  <refinement-list attribute="sample" title="Sample" />
</div>
```

However the problem is that only the first component is rendered, see working example:
https://codepen.io/javiervd/pen/vYBpQMm

I tried registering the component locally instead but no luck. I'm also using Vue with a script tag in my app because I can't use a build system for this particular project, not sure if that matters.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are defining the template in the DOM, you can't use self-closing tags for the custom components.

This should work:

```
<div id="app">
  <refinement-list attribute="test" title="Test"></refinement-list>
  <refinement-list attribute="sample" title="Sample"></refinement-list>
</div>
```

This limitation doesn't exist in template strings or Single File Components.

You can read more about this here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue!

Answer (score 3):

You should give like this in the HTML section if you want to use the self-closing tags. But it's not recommended for DOM Templates

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
  <refinement-list attribute="test" title="Test1" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <refinement-list attribute="test" title="Test2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why does this happen? I'm using Vue with Laravel and this was the only way I managed to solve this issue, it's kinda weird as I already added some divs inside each component to see if that works, it didn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

I forked your codepen and can confirm this is working with the separate closing tag style, in place of using self-closing tags for the components.

```
<div id="app">
  <refinement-list attribute="test" title="Test"></refinement-list>
  <refinement-list attribute="sample" title="Sample"></refinement-list>
</div>
```

ref: https://codepen.io/edm00se/pen/pozpqym?editors=1010

The self-closing tag versus (full?) closing tag [is discussed in the vue style guide page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended) (v2) and it is expressed that for string templates (as I suspect codepen is doing when loading your HTML content), to use the closing tag, while self-closing are fine in single-file components, JSX, and string templates (things which are processed during build and component names are better known).